# Memcached server refuses connections

Tags: php, session, memcached, ufw

My webservers are refusing to connect to the memached server. Both php.ini and memcached.ini are adjusted to the new memcached ip xx.xx.71.5 .

The webservers (xx.xx.13.32 / xx.xx.13.16) are allowed to connect.

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
127.0.0.1 11211/tcp        ALLOW       127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1 11211/tcp        ALLOW       xx.xx.13.16
127.0.0.1 11211/tcp        ALLOW       xx.xx.13.32
Anywhere                   ALLOW       xx.xx.13.32
Anywhere                   ALLOW       xx.xx.13.16
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
Anywhere                   ALLOW       127.0.0.1
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

How is it possible that the webservers can't connect to the memcached server.

telnet xx.xx.71.5 gives me the answer, connection refused.

Comment: telnet is port 23, so no wonder that's not working. and for memcached to be accessible from outside, allowing 127.0.0.1 is pointless, since that's localhost-only. you need to allow port 11211 on all ips, from those server ips.

Comment: @MarcB isn't that what is mentioned here? 127.0.0.1 11211/tcp        ALLOW       xx.xx.13.16
127.0.0.1 11211/tcp        ALLOW       xx.xx.13.32

Comment: you can't connect to "127.0.0.1" from outside the machine. EVERY machine is its own 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Unknown: Failed to write session data (memcached). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (xx.xx.71.5:11211) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: added telnet ports. Still no response. 23 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
23/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

Comment: are you connecting via ipv6? if it's a v4 connection, then those will be blocked, since you only opened v6 ports.

Comment: use `telnet xxx.xxx.71.5 11211` to test connectivity to the memcached server

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume that you are on RedHat Linux. You will find the read-only memcached config at /etc/sysconfig/memcached (If installed using yum).

Go ahead and give yourself write permissions. There'll be a line as this:
`OPTIONS="-l 172.xx.xx.xx,::1"`

The only difference being, I replaced 127.0.0.1 with my external IP so that another server can access this. Hope this solves the issue.

PS: Though this is an old question, answering to provide insights to others with a similar problem!